# How can I handle http requests of different methods to / in Go?

Tags: go

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle requests to `/` and only `/` in Go and handle different methods in different ways. Here's the best I've come up with:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.URL.Path != "/" {
            http.NotFound(w, r)
            return
        }

        if r.Method == "GET" {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "GET, %q", html.EscapeString(r.URL.Path))
        } else if r.Method == "POST" {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "POST, %q", html.EscapeString(r.URL.Path))
        } else {
            http.Error(w, "Invalid request method.", 405)
        }
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Is this idiomatic Go? Is this the best I can do with the standard http lib? I'd much rather do something like `http.HandleGet("/", handler)` as in express or Sinatra. Is there a good framework for writing simple REST services? [web.go](https://github.com/hoisie/web) looks attractive but appears stagnant.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: you may be interested in http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux if you're only looking for a routing abstraction.

Comment: +1. mux or http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/pat are excellent for abstracting this.

Comment: Gorilla's Mux toolkit is now a public archive.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

To ensure that you only serve the root: You're doing the right thing. In some cases you would want to call the ServeHttp method of an http.FileServer object instead of calling NotFound; it depends whether you have miscellaneous files that you want to serve as well.

To handle different methods differently: Many of my HTTP handlers contain nothing but a switch statement like this:

```
switch r.Method {
case http.MethodGet:
    // Serve the resource.
case http.MethodPost:
    // Create a new record.
case http.MethodPut:
    // Update an existing record.
case http.MethodDelete:
    // Remove the record.
default:
    http.Error(w, "Method not allowed", http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
}
```

Of course, you may find that a third-party package like gorilla works better for you.

Comment: In the default branch "Give an error message" you should return HTTP Status Code 405 i.e. `w.WriteHeader(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)`

Comment: @SergeyPonomarev `http.Error` [does this for you](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/63d05642d48ec81637481518df962f2b3be435a3/src/net/http/server.go#L2117)

Answer (score 47):

eh, I was actually heading to bed and thus the quick comment on looking at http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux which is really nice and does what you want, just give the docs a look over. For example

```
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)
    r.HandleFunc("/products", ProductsHandler)
    r.HandleFunc("/articles", ArticlesHandler)
    http.Handle("/", r)
}
```

and

```
r.HandleFunc("/products", ProductsHandler).
    Host("www.domain.com").
    Methods("GET").
    Schemes("http")
```

and many other possibilities and ways to perform the above operations.

But I felt a need to address the other part of the question, "Is this the best I can do". If the std lib is a little too bare, a great resource to check out is here: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Projects#web-libraries (linked specifically to web libraries).

Comment: And don't forget to register your new router `r` as a handler in your `Server` instance